# How to store the output generated in python in a txt file

Tags: python, file, input, output

So I have a code like this:

```
disfile = open('filename.txt')
for line in disfile:
    list = line.split()
    id = list[4]
    if id == 'sequence':
        name = list[0]
        Sequence = list[5]
    elif id == 'disorder':
        Disorder = list[5]
        print name, ' ', 'Sequence:',' ', Sequence,' ', 'Disorder:',' ', Disorder
```

And after that all the data and sequence are printed in the python editor or IDLE. But I want to generate a file which contains all the things that have been printed. Can anyone help me please!

So my file looks like this:

> 101M : A : sequence MVLSEGEWQLVLHVWAKVEADVAGHGQDILIRLFKSHPETLEKFDRVKHLKTEAEMKASEDLKKHGVTVLTALGAILKKKGHHEAELKPLAQSHATKHKIPIKYLEFISEAIIHVLHSRHPGNFGADAQGAMNKALELFRKDIAAKYKELGYQG
>   101M : A : secstr    HHHHHHHHHHHHHHGGGHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH GGGGGG TTTTT  SHHHHHH HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHTTTT  HHHHHHHHHHHHHTS   HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH GGG SHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHTT
>   101M : A : disorder ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   102L : A : sequence MNIFEMLRIDEGLRLKIYKDTEGYYTIGIGHLLTKSPSLNAAAKSELDKAIGRNTNGVITKDEAEKLFNQDVDAAVRGILRNAKLKPVYDSLDAVRRAALINMVFQMGETGVAGFTNSLRMLQQKRWDEAAVNLAKSRWYNQTPNRAKRVITTFRTGTWDAYKNL
>   102L : A : secstr  HHHHHHHHH  EEEEEE TTS EEEETTEEEESSS TTTHHHHHHHHHHTS  TTB  HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH TTHHHHHHHS HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHT HHHHHHHHTT HHHHHHHHHSSHHHHHSHHHHHHHHHHHHHSSSGGG
>   102L : A : disorder -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------XX
>   102M : A : sequence MVLSEGEWQLVLHVWAKVEADVAGHGQDILIRLFKSHPETLEKFDRFKHLKTEAEMKASEDLKKAGVTVLTALGAILKKKGHHEAELKPLAQSHATKHKIPIKYLEFISEAIIHVLHSRHPGNFGADAQGAMNKALELFRKDIAAKYKELGYQG
>   102M : A : secstr    HHHHHHHHHHHHHHGGGHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH GGGGGG TTTTT  SHHHHHH HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHTTTT  HHHHHHHHHHHHHTS   HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH TTT  HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHT
>   102M : A : disorder ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   103L : A : sequence MNIFEMLRIDEGLRLKIYKDTEGYYTIGIGHLLTKSPSLNSLDAAKSELDKAIGRNTNGVITKDEAEKLFNQDVDAAVRGILRNAKLKPVYDSLDAVRRAALINMVFQMGETGVAGFTNSLRMLQQKRWDEAAVNLAKSRWYNQTPNRAKRVITTFRTGTWDAYKNL
>   103L : A : secstr  HHHHHHHHH  EEEEEE TTS EEEETTEE         HHHHHHHHHHHHTS  TTB  HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH TTTHHHHHHS HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHT HHHHHHHHTT HHHHHHHHHSSHHHHHSHHHHHHHHHHHHHSSSGGG
>   103L : A : disorder ----------------------------------XXXXXX-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------XX

And After I added the code:

import sys
sys.stdout = open('outputfile', 'w')
print 'test' #'test' will be in the output file

Therefore my code becomes:

```
disfile = open('filename.txt')
for line in disfile:
    list = line.split()
    id = list[4]
    if id == 'sequence':
        name = list[0]
        Sequence = list[5]
    elif id == 'disorder':
        Disorder = list[5]
        import sys
        sys.stdout = open('newfile.txt', 'w')
        print name, ' ', 'Sequence:',' ', Sequence,' ', 'Disorder:',' ', Disorder
```

It did generate a file, but only the last sequence appeared in the file, what happened?

Comment: Pipe it into a file with your shell: `python foo.py > file.txt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is only saving the last sequence because on each iteration it is opening the file again and overwriting. You should open it before the loop.

But I'd recommend using writes or print "chevron" format. i.e.:

```
f = open('outputfile', 'w')
for .....
    print >>f,name, ' ', 'Sequence:',' ', Sequence,' ', 'Disorder:',' ', Disorder
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either write to a file you open using `write()` or redirect `stdout` so that all the output via `print` will go to a file:

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open('outputfile', 'w')
print 'test' #'test' will be in the outputfile
```

You can also pipe into a file as Blender mentioned in a comment using `>` however that only applies if you're using a shell rather than the Python editor or IDLE as you mentioned.

Replacing `stdout` isn't something that should be done in production code since it is replaced globally, i.e. the output of other functions external to your code will also end up in the file. You might want to save the original `sys.stdout` if you do replace it.

Comment: Replacing `sys.stdout` is not a good idea. You replace it globally.

Comment: @user3817527, you're assigning to `sys.stdout` multiple times. Try assigning once at the start of the code. There's no need to do it multiple times. Every time you assign it again, you overwrite what used to be in that file (hence only the *last* iteration's output appears).

Comment: @Blender, noted in answer :)